# Thymeleaf + Polymer

Tags: spring-mvc, polymer, thymeleaf

I'm trying to implement material design based on Polymer with Java Thymeleaf template engine. I started learning by this [tutorial](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html) and got this exception:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Attribute name "unresolved" associated with an element type "body" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

As far as I can understand Thymeleaf, by default can't deal with web components/custom components. Is it possible to use Polymer in context of Thymeleaf template engine?

Comment: It is difficult to provide any inputs without seeing the files or a sample project.  Could you post the Thymeleaf template you are using or a link to a Gist containing the relevant files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have something like:

```
<body unresolved touch-action="auto">
```

it will not work with Thymeleaf because Thymeleaf expects the markup to be valid XHTML and `unresolved` on its own is invalid XHTML markup.  The following however should work:

```
<body unresolved="" touch-action="auto">
<body unresolved="unresolved" touch-action="auto">
```

Answer (score 2):

The upcoming Thymeleaf 3.0 release will be able to deal with non-XHTML markup at lot better than Thymeleaf 2.1.

Have a look at

http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Thymeleaf-3-0-status-td4029243.html